# question on open connectedness in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

My question is regarding an intermediary 'lemma' to deduce path-connectedness from an open connected set in Euclidean space. How does one prove that for any $x,y\in U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $U$ is open and connected, there are finitely many intermediate points $x_1,...,x_k\in U$ such that the segments $[x_1,x_2],...[x_{k-1},x_k] $ all lie in $U$?

Comment: Fix $x \in U$ and consider $V$ to be the subset of $U$ that can be connected to $x$ by finitely many line segments which lie in $U$. Now prove that $V$ and $U\setminus V$ are both open. Use connectedness of $U$.

Comment: Yes, this is how I would prove that the set is path connected, directly. In fact I would let $U$ be the set that can be connected to $x$ by one path. But is there a way to count explicitly these intermediate points between $x$ and $y$?